# C# service reference doesn't recognize the query parameter from url

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I've added in the service reference an url like this: "https://example.com/cars?wsdl"

Everything works fine, I can access the methods from that soap and compile the project without errors.

When I call a method the endpoint address is https://example.com/cars (I've notice this with the debugger) on this page is only a fault error and every method I call it returns the fault error.

Why the service reference doesn't see the parameter "?wsdl" ?

Thanks!

Comment: Together with Visual Studio You probably have installed a tool called WcfTestClient. Try to call the service using it and let us know if You get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your fault message is probably coming from the service itself.  The `?wsdl` at the end just has information about your service.  Put a try catch in the method that you're calling on the service layer.

Comment: I surrounded the calling method with try catch and catches the fault exception from the https://example.com/cars

<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>
No such operation: null (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /carsnull)
</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>

If I call the method from POSTMAN with plain xml using the address https://example.com/cars?wsdl everything works fine.

Thanks for response!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using xml request.

http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/

The error seems to be from the service itself.